# How to Upload my CodeIgniter Project in 000webhost

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I created one CodeIgniter project and it is working fine in my localhost,i removed index.php in that project and directly i am accessing the default controller /localhost/code2/....  everything is working fine...

what i want is,i want to upload same in 000webhost,i copied all the ci file and paste in public_html folder in 000webhost but it show 404error.

//.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

helpme to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Remove every thing from .htaccess that resolved my issue . and make sure that your codeigniter file should be in That folder which is link to your domain

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

to :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
```